# Is there a way to list tags order by post_meta field

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, tags

Im working on a plugin. I placed like button under each post so users can like the post. When user click the button it updates 'likes_count' post_meta field which i created. Now here is my question. I created an admin page and i want to list all the tags order by 'likes_count' post_meta field. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "tags" here? Do you mean Wordpress Tags as in the taxonomy ('post_tag') - some kind of list of Tags ordered by most likes of Posts with that Tag? Or do you mean something completely different?

Comment: yes.. possible
When clicking on like button it updates the likes_count post meta. Now you query using $wpdb or wp_query  get all posts or tags or category using order by likes_count > 0. I am just giving you an idea. If you are not able to do that comment here, I will give you example code...

Comment: @FaysalMahamud I already solved the button problem. I just need to list tags order by likes_count but i don't know how. If you give me example query i would appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CKMacLeod Yes that's exactly what i want

Comment: OK - will have to think about it. It appears to me that Faysal Muhammad is just comparing like vs 0 likes, but you want something where all the likes of posts with tag Foo are counted up, so, a post with 20 likes under Foo gives Foo a count of "20", equivalent to 20 posts with 1 like each under tag Bar. I think it's possible, but on a large site with many tags you might need to take different approach than for a small site with only a few tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
    -- post_meta.meta_value,
    key2.name as tag_name,key2.slug as tag_slug FROM $wpdb->posts key1
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (key1.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta post_meta ON (key1.ID = post_meta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms key2 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = key2.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy key3 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = key3.term_id)
  WHERE 1=1
  AND post_meta.meta_key = 'likes_count'
  AND post_meta.meta_value > 0
  AND (key1.post_status = 'publish')
  AND key3.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
print_r($pageposts);
```

This is the exact query for tags. I tested this and worked fine.
in below given you sample output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tag_name] => Tag1
            [tag_slug] => tag1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tag_name] => Tag2
            [tag_slug] => tag2
        )

)
```

Comment: I tried it now and it works like charm!! Thanks a lot. One more thing, i also want to list likes_count. How can i do this?

Comment: You want 
  Tag1(count value) or anything else...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a meta query which filters by post meta and then put the wordpress orderby variable to meta_key

Comment: Can you please explain what that means? Preferably with a short code example.

Comment: I will tonight :)